# How to delete the cart item from local storage?

Tags: javascript

When I click the delete icon I want to delete from DOM element but do not delete from local storage. How can I fix this problem?

```
function deleteProduct(e) {
  let cartItem;
  if (e.target.className === 'delete') {
    cartItem = e.target.parentElement;
    cartItem.remove(); // this removes from the DOM only
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'I') {
    cartItem = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    cartItem.remove(); // this removes from the DOM only
  }

  let products = getProductFromStorage();
  let updatedProducts = products.filter((product) => {
    return product.id !== parseInt(cartItem.dataset.id);
  });
  localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(updatedProducts)); // updating the product list after the deletion
  updateCartInfo();
}
```

```js
function addToCartList(product) {
    const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
    cartItem.classList.add('cart-item');
    cartItem.setAttribute('data-id', $ {
        product.id
    });
    cartItem.innerHTML = `<table> <tr> <td class="image"> <img src=${product.imgSrc} alt="" /> </td> <td class="name">${product.name}</td> <td class="price">${product.price}</td> <td class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td> </tr> </table> `;
    cartList.appendChild(cartItem);
}
```

Comment: `product.id !== cartItem;` seems strange. I expect `product.id` to be a string or number and `cartItem` to be a HTML elementt. The filter condition always true.

Comment: Could you also include the relevant markups? `cartItem` is an `Element` and you are comparing it with an ID

Comment: ```return product.id !== cartItem;```  cartItem is not a number but a DOM element.

Comment: return product.id !== cartItem.dataset.id;

is also not working

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan, a quick question. Are you using ```reactjs``` or not? You tag reactjs in your question, but you remove your DOM element using ```cartItem.remove()```.

Comment: console.log(products). Is it what you expect? You might want to share getProductFromStorage code too.

Comment: this is vanilla js project

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan, did you set the id in the attribute as ```data-id```? Please provide some HTML examples.

Comment: @ikhvjs yes i'll set data-id attirbute...

function addToCartList(product) {
  const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
  cartItem.classList.add('cart-item');
  cartItem.setAttribute('data-id', `${product.id}`);
  cartItem.innerHTML = `
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="image">
          <img src=${product.imgSrc} alt="" />
        </td>
        <td class="name">${product.name}</td>
        <td class="price">${product.price}</td>
        <td class="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `;
  cartList.appendChild(cartItem);
}

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan, please update your question with the HTML instead of leave it in the comment.

Comment: @ikhvjs I'm new in StackOverflow... I'm having trouble with this

Comment: so far I notice you have syntax error when you try to set the ```data-id```. Try replace this one with```cartItem.setAttribute("data-id", product.id);```